# Import large csv-file into Drupal 7

Tags: csv, drupal, drupal-7, feed, drupal-feeds

Is it possible to load huge csv files (58K lines, 600K lines ) into Drupal 7 database using Feeds module?
 I've tried on pair of hosting servers. On the first server it has been loaded 1050 records from 58K, on another - 100(from the same file). There is no any error message but csv file loaded partially.

Is any suggestions?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: have you checked or atered `max_execution_time` in your php.ini?

Comment: You should try these recommendations, it helped me: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1551246#comment-7746079

Comment: I can't check up php.ini, haven't any rights.

Comment: About cron it's not quiet clear for me how to set up cron job and why it doesn't work. I've read a lot form internet but 've found nothing to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to import in the background or on submission?

For an import of that size you will need to run the import in the background.

This will use cron to run the feeds cron job, Drupal uses a poor-mans cron so it would be best to setup a cron on the server if you know how. if not you could try something link https://www.pingdom.com (you can use a free account) to ping your site every minute to trigger the poor-mans corn.

I would also make sure that your server is optimal for Drupal 7. (mem, cpu, php config)

I personally import 57K pdfs into Drupal using feeds so it is possible.

Comment: I haven't any righs to set up cron on server. And what is the difference runing job in background if it also load a part of the csv-file and stop working?

Comment: It sounds like the server is running out of resources, running the job in the background will do a part of the import each time a cron is run. Since you don't have root access to the server you will have to setup a Pingdom account to ping the site (poor-man cron relies on site activity to run so to ensure you have enough activity to run the cron setup a ping every minute)

Comment: Also you may not get any errors showing depending on how the server is configured..try looking in the Drupal log if you haven't already.

Comment: It's not clear for me and I don't understand how  server remembers where it stopped previous import and from what line to start on the next cron event? So if it starts from the begining what the reason to do it every minute, for example?(and import the same 1050 records instead of 58K)

Comment: I've checked up Drupal log. Nothing interesting, just "Cron started in a thread 1" message and nothing else.

Comment: Your CSV file should have a GUID which the import uses as an ID for when importing. make sure it is mapped to GUID in the feeds import.

Comment: Huh! That is it, may be!! My CSV file has ID , but I didn't map it as GUID.
Let me try.

Comment: Well! Nothing. I've mapped GUID to unique field from csv file. 've installed 
"Ultimate cron" and "Feeds ultimate cron integration" modules. Set up import job, time interval - 15 minutes ...and NOTHING!! Job starts every 15 minutes according to system log but 1050 records and no one more record. There is no any error or warnig message, WTF?

Comment: Those modules are still only poor man cron, they just give you more control over which cron are fired when... did you setup a Pingdom account to ping the website every min?

Comment: No! I ping it manually because this is testing domain and this domain is unknown for other internet users. But...oh my eyes! It looks like it starts to work. UTF-8 encoding ??? I've found on one of the tabs that there is an error, saying "File is not UTF-8 encoding" and I've encoded it into UTF-8 and started import again. 10500 records are in for this moment.

Comment: Ping basically simulates users active on the site to TRIGGER cron.. If the feeds cron is running 200 entires at each 15min cron trigger you could be there a while.

Comment: I afraid to start cron every minute because hoster could block my activity and to be blocked is not my goal!)

Comment: ok, well is sounds like its working? just going to take you a while with the manual ping?

Comment: no, I'll set up scheduled task on my Win10 computer. It will ping! It looks like there was  encoding problem, but it needs some investigation to be sure.

Comment: ok message back when you have more info and I'll see if I can help

Comment: Something escapes my attention but what? 
Cron doesn't start by site ping. I've tested it on two hosting servers. Pinging them every minute, every 15  minutes or constantly cron on both sites doesn't start until I open any page on a site. Hm???
Well,after installing two modules "Feeds ultimate cron integration" and "Ultimate cron" I've got ability to configure every job separately. 
I've set up Feeds Importer(set up 15 minutes interval for import), I've set up cron job for every 15 minutes interval and...cron doesn't start...

Comment: With the default cron module, on the cron settings page, there should be a link you can click to trigger the cron.. 'To run cron from outside the site'

Comment: Thats the link you use on Pingdom. (sorry my bad I didn't think to tell you that bit)

Comment: Yes I know about cron link and I tried to start it from task scheduler but unsuccessfully...))). And Pingdom is not a free of charge service,isn't it?
On drupal.com I've found cronless.com  - another cron service and isn't free too...

Comment: I've not used Pingdom for a while but you used to able to have a free account with one website you could ping... Not sure whats going on with your cron, is it disabled in your settings.php ?

Comment: Nothing is mentioned about cron in my settings.php. It works but only if I open site pages.

Comment: Hmmm... hard to say whats going, can you post/pm a screenshot of your cron settings and your Pingdom account settings?